# Compilation error when using LuaPlus

Tags: c++, lua, luaplus

I found a nice tutorial on how to implement LuaPlus into an C++ Project using Visual Studio 2010.
http://www.zynox.net/luaplus-1-compiling-basic-usage/
But I can't get it to work because of some error messages..

```
mainproject\main.cpp(51): error C2664: ‘GetCurrentDirectoryW’ : cannot convert parameter 2 from ‘char [260]‘ to ‘LPWSTR’

50. char pPath[ MAX_PATH ];
51. GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,pPath);
52. strcat_s(pPath,MAX_PATH,"\\test.lua");
```

I tried to use TCHAR instead of char, but then it says:

```
no instance of overloaded function “strcat_s” matches the argument list
```

So for testing purposes I just deleted these three lines and replaced them with a static path:

```
const char* pPath = "C:\\Users\\fancyBubble\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\LuaPlusTutorial\\MainProject\\test.lua";
```

and now I get:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ‘..\Debug\LUAPlus.lib’
```

I'm absolutely clueless how to fix this.
I even tried to use the same version of LuaPlus that the tutorial-creator probably used, but the error messages didn't go away.

Comment: Make sure `UNICODE` is *not* defined otherwise the macro from `winbase.h` will replace `GetCurrentDirectory` with `GetCurrentDirectoryW`. You can also explicitly use the non-unicode version `GetCurrentDirectoryA`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to "Multi-Byte Character Set", this fixes the first error... But the "fatal error" remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what I did wrong, but the admin uploaded the whole solution:
http://www.zynox.net/?wpfb_dl=3

Using this combined with greatwolf's comment it works great. :)